# Some trucks are highly customized with flashy metal, horns, and lights, what are they called?

Tags: word-choice

I particularly notice the creativity with dump trucks and small pickups, customized interiors too. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are called [デコトラ](https://search.yahoo.co.jp/image/search?ei=UTF-8&p=%E3%83%87%E3%82%B3%E3%83%88%E3%83%A9), which stands for デコレーション・トラック.

Oh, there's even [an article on English Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dekotora).